# How to assign number in an excel column based on conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I have four columns in Excel which shows values, they are either positive, negative or zero values.

Based on the values we need to assign values in a new column. If all values are positive then we should assign a value as 1. If all values are negative then we should assign a value as 2 and so on. We have 72 such combinations.

Apart from NESTED IF, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the MIN/MAX test @Gary's Student posted you could also format as a nested if statement allowing a bit more flexibility of the output you want.

`=if(MIN(A1:D1)>0, 1, if(MAX(A1:D1)<0, 2, 0))`.

If the first if() is true it returns 1, if not it tests the second if() and if that is true it returns 2 else it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Say we look at **A1** through **D1**.
Assume that all cells have numbers. *(no blanks)*

If all values are positive, then `MIN(A1:D1)` will be greater than zero.
If all values are negative, then `MAX(A1:D1)` will be less than zero.

In your case, it is easy to avoid nested `IF`s.  We can use *Boolean factors*.  In **E1** enter:

```
=(MIN(A1:D1)>0)*1 + (MAX(A1:D1)<0)*2
```

this works because each term is mutually exclusive:

[image]

You can add as many term as you like.

*(I would considering using a VBA macro instead)*

You could also construct a `VLOOKUP()` table.

**EDIT#1:**

Use `VLOOKUP()`

We will first assign a code word for each row.  The code word will describe the [**+ 0 -**] status of the row's contents.

the words will be like *AAAA* or *ACBA*, etc.  *A* for negative, *B* for zero, *C* for positive.  In **E1** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(SIGN(A1)+2,"A","B","C")&CHOOSE(SIGN(B1)+2,"A","B","C")&CHOOSE(SIGN(C1)+2,"A","B","C")&CHOOSE(SIGN(D1)+2,"A","B","C")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Now that we have the code words, we can make a vlookup table to get the associated numbers.  In column **H** list the code words that may occur and next to each the desired numeric value:

[image]

Finally in **F1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,H:I,2,)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.
However, not necessarily I will have all positive or negative values. There can be combination of both positive and negative values. Sometimes it could be zero as well in any of the four columns. I believe the above formula you have mentioned might not work in that case. Is there a way to achieve it. Sorry if I wasn't clear on my request earlier.

Comment: @SiddharthaDeshavali See my **EDIT#1**